# beaglebone and turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I had to offload most of the computation done for a project I'm working on to another computer, I wanted to substitute the netbook I'm using right now on my homebrew turtlebot with a system on a chip, like the beaglebone black. I wanted to know if it was enough to handle pretty much just the kinect and the serial interface to the Create, or if I had to consider other systems. From what I've read, it seems like it would be better to use a dual core SoC, like the pandaboard, but it would cost me more than using two other "smaller" SoCs, so another possibility I was considering was to use more than one board and further distribute the nodes among them (eg, one board dedicated to the kinect and the other to the create). Can anyone offer some advise?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146926/beaglebone-and-turtlebot/) by [Orgrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/8621/orgrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-01**:
@kalectro might have something to say about it?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2014-04-01**:
I agree with @ahendrix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The general consensus from the people who have tried is that the Beaglebone and other small ARM boards don't have enough CPU power or USB bandwidth to handle the full-resolution data stream from the Kinect well.

This is made even worse on a number of boards where the ethernet interface is attached to the USB bus, requiring the kinect and the network port to share bandwidth. The kinect uses something like 90% of the theoretical USB bandwidth, ethernet is another 20%, and then there's overhead in the protocol to be accounted for as well; the numbers just don't add up.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1